# How to show error when unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, xcode, refactoring

I refactor my code, so, I have to rename some function. But in other branch of git, other one still use function with old name. And it will be crashed if I miss a change to new function name.

So, how can I make unrecognized selector as error (to prevent build success), instead of warning

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With ARC enabled, the compilator will treat this warning as an error, so you should enable ARC in your project. If you don't want to convert your project to ARC, you can instead set the `Treat Warnings as Errors` flag to `Yes`.

Comment: I have many warning from other teammate, I cannot fix all warning. So, I only want change "no selector warning" to error

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Xcode build settings, turn all the warnings on, and turn on "Warnings = Error". There are only three or four warnings that I have disabled.

BTW. It's no problem if the program crashes, because it is an obvious error that can be fixed easily when it happens. Turn on breakpoints for Objective-C exceptions, and your debugger will stop right on the call that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't care if it crash when I debugging. But I worry if it crash when I published app with a missing error. I don't want all warning will become error